# Do I need to create a new descriptor set for every buffer?

Tags: 3d, vulkan, compute-shader

I'm new to graphics programming and Vulkan. 
I understand that we need bind buffer to a descriptor set, but I'm wondering if I need a new descriptor set for every buffer I have or can I descriptorSet can bind 2/more buffers? 
If yes, whats the rule of thumb for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each descriptor set may have multiple resources of the same or different type. What type of resources can be bound through a descriptor set is defined in a descriptor set layout. There, through a VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding structure, You specify a given type of a resource (for example sampler, storage image or uniform buffer) and the number of resources of this type accessed as an array inside shader. But You can also specify multiple resources of the same type as separate layout entries (multiple VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding entries specified during layout creation). Each such descriptor must use a separate, different binding. And the same binding must be used inside shader to access given resource:

```
layout( set=S, binding=B ) uniform <variable_type> <variable_name>;
```

As for the second part of Your question - it depends. Each situation, drawn scene, type of rendered resources, number of resources, memory usage, even graphics hardware vendor influence the approach used to create and bind descriptor sets during rendering. General rule is that You should minimize state changes during rendering. So You should keep the number of vkCmdBindDescriptorSets() function calls as small as possible. But this limits both flexibility and dynamic of Your scene. So there many situations in which You will need to change descriptors, or bind multiple descriptors at once each with multiple descriptors. But, as I have written, it all depends on a given situation.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need separate descriptor set for each resource.

Documentation of [VkDescriptorSetLayout](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#VkDescriptorSetLayout) seems to make clear what is happening. There is also nice code example demonstrating this in the same chapter.

So, to sum that up:

- You can have an (homogenous) array of a single descriptor type
- You can have several "bindings" which each can hold any descriptor type resource (or their array)
- And as one more layer of indirection you can have several descriptor sets each with its own bindings

Rule of thumb is probably "less is more". If you do not need the resources to have separate types or names, use array. If you do not need separate set, use only one set.